# WinJS application still running when suspended

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have a WinJS application that contains a timer object in it. I've read from the msdn docs that my application would be suspended after 5 seconds from the user navigating to another application, after which my app would stop running.

However, on testing the application in the suspended state, I've noticed that the timer keeps running. I've tried suspending the application by

1. Clicking the "suspend" button from VS2012 debug window and
2. Manually running my application, navigating to another application and waiting for a while(10mins) to get it suspended.

But in both cases, the timer keeps running. I expected it to stop at the point of suspension and resume with the same time when it is resumed, but instead it showed the elapsed time correctly.

I'd appreciate if anyone could explain this behavior. I'm running Windows 8 Release Preview.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by timer?

Comment: Oops sorry, Timer's the name I gave it. It's an object that has a setTimeout reference variable, which I use as a countdown timer.

Comment: And it's firing while you are suspended, executing code? The timer will fie when you come out of suspend, it doesn't get cancelled. It Will just fire when you come back from being suspended. I'd recommend testing with out the debugger.

Comment: Yes, the callback is firing even when the app is in the suspended state, which according to MS, should not happen. Actually, I'm glad that it's running while suspended because it means less work for me(no need to keep track of the application's state), but I don't know if I can rely on this anomalous behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All timers are suspended when the app is suspended. I just verified it with this code:

```
function timerFired() {
    var container = document.getElementById("timeroutput");
    var content = document.createElement("div");
    content.textContent = Date.now();

    container.appendChild(content);
}

setInterval(timerFired, 1000);
```

When the app goes in the background, and suspends (which takes ~15 seconds before it's suspended), the text stops being appended to.

Note that:

- While under the debugger the app is *not* automatically suspended, and you have to click the suspend button (as you say you are doing).
- If you activate the application after suspension (e.g. click it, or switch back to it) the timer will execute immediately if the time it's been suspended is *longer* than the timer interval
- if you are playing background audio correctly, then your timer will still run because you **don't** get suspended while you are playing background audio

Comment: I just tried your code and found that the app indeed was being suspended, the reason it appeared not to be was that I had a new Date object created each time in the callback that was used to calculate the elapsed time . And once the app was resumed, it ran showing the correct elapsed time(because a new Date object was being created on resumption), stupid me! Thanks a lot for your answer, I might have never cared to look more closely if it weren't for your answer.